# Invoke delegate() from another CS file?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, delegates, filesystems

I am trying to practice an example of file watch. So the basic idea is to create an independent thread that monitors any events in the watched folder. The original program is windows form based, and I am trying to convert it to frame work 3.5, C# + WPF;

The delegate functions that responses to event is defined in A.cs, and they look like:

```
public class WatcherEx : IDisposable
    {
        #region Data Members
        private bool           disposed    = false;
        private WatcherInfo    watcherInfo = null;
        private WatchersExList watchers    = new WatchersExList();
        #endregion Data Members

        #region Event Definitions
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedAttribute     = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedCreationTime  = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedDirectoryName = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedFileName      = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedLastAccess    = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedLastWrite     = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedSecurity      = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventChangedSize          = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventCreated              = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventDeleted              = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventRenamed              = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventError                = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventDisposed             = delegate {};
        public event WatcherExEventHandler EventPathAvailability     = delegate {};
        #endregion Event Definitions

        #region Constructors
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public WatcherEx(WatcherInfo info)
        {
            if (info == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("WatcherInfo object cannot be null");
            }
            this.watcherInfo = info;

            Initialize();
        }
        #endregion Constructors

        #region Dispose Methods
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes all of the FileSystemWatcher objects, and disposes this object.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WatcherEx.Dispose()");
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                DisposeWatchers();
                this.disposed = true;
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes of all of our watchers (called from Dispose, or as a result of 
        /// loosing access to a folder)
        /// </summary>
        public void DisposeWatchers()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WatcherEx.DisposeWatchers()");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.watchers.Count; i++)
            {
                this.watchers[i].Dispose();
            }
            this.watchers.Clear();
        }
        #endregion Dispose Methods

        #region Helper Methods
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the specified NotifyFilter item has been specified to be 
        /// handled by this object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool HandleNotifyFilter(NotifyFilters filter)
        {
            return (((NotifyFilters)(this.watcherInfo.ChangesFilters & filter)) == filter);
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the specified WatcherChangeType item has been specified to be 
        /// handled by this object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool HandleWatchesFilter(WatcherChangeTypes filter)
        {
            return (((WatcherChangeTypes)(this.watcherInfo.WatchesFilters & filter)) == filter);
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes this oibject by creating all of the required internal 
        /// FileSystemWatcher objects necessary to mointor the folder/file for the 
        /// desired changes
        /// </summary>
        private void Initialize()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WatcherEx.Initialize()");
            // the buffer can be from 4 to 64 kbytes.  Default is 8
            this.watcherInfo.BufferKBytes = Math.Max(4, Math.Min(this.watcherInfo.BufferKBytes, 64));

            // create the main watcher (handles create/delete, rename, error, and dispose)
            // can't pass a null enum type, so we just pass ta dummy one on the first call
            CreateWatcher(false, this.watcherInfo.ChangesFilters);
            // create a change watcher for each NotifyFilter item
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.Attributes);
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.CreationTime);
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.DirectoryName);
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.FileName);
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.LastAccess);
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.LastWrite);
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.Security);
            CreateWatcher(true, NotifyFilters.Size);

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("WatcherEx.Initialize() - {0} watchers created", this.watchers.Count));
        }


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Actually creates the necessary FileSystemWatcher objects, depending oin which 
        /// notify filters and change types the user specified.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="changeType"></param>
        /// <param name="filter"></param>
        private void CreateWatcher(bool changedWatcher, NotifyFilters filter)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("WatcherEx.CreateWatcher({0}, {1})", changedWatcher.ToString(), filter.ToString()));

            FileSystemWatcherEx watcher = null;
            int bufferSize = (int)this.watcherInfo.BufferKBytes * 1024;
            // Each "Change" filter gets its own watcher so we can determine *what* 
            // actually changed. This will allow us to react only to the change events 
            // that we actually want.  The reason I do this is because some programs 
            // fire TWO events for  certain changes. For example, Notepad sends two 
            // events when a file is created. One for CreationTime, and one for 
            // Attributes.
            if (changedWatcher)
            {
                // if we're not handling the currently specified filter, get out
                if (HandleNotifyFilter(filter))
                {
                    watcher                       = new FileSystemWatcherEx(this.watcherInfo.WatchPath);
                    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = this.watcherInfo.IncludeSubFolders;
                    watcher.Filter                = this.watcherInfo.FileFilter;
                    watcher.NotifyFilter          = filter;
                    watcher.InternalBufferSize    = bufferSize;
                    switch (filter)
                    {
                        case NotifyFilters.Attributes    :
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedAttribute);
                            break;
                        case NotifyFilters.CreationTime  : 
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedCreationTime);
                            break;
                        case NotifyFilters.DirectoryName : 
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedDirectoryName);
                            break;
                        case NotifyFilters.FileName      : 
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedFileName);
                            break;
                        case NotifyFilters.LastAccess    : 
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedLastAccess);
                            break;
                        case NotifyFilters.LastWrite     : 
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedLastWrite);
                            break;
                        case NotifyFilters.Security      : 
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedSecurity);
                            break;
                        case NotifyFilters.Size          : 
                            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_ChangedSize);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // All other FileSystemWatcher events are handled through a single "main" 
            // watcher.
            else
            {
                if (HandleWatchesFilter(WatcherChangeTypes.Created) ||
                    HandleWatchesFilter(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted) ||
                    HandleWatchesFilter(WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed) ||
                    this.watcherInfo.WatchForError ||
                    this.watcherInfo.WatchForDisposed)
                {
                    watcher                       = new FileSystemWatcherEx(this.watcherInfo.WatchPath, watcherInfo.MonitorPathInterval);
                    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = this.watcherInfo.IncludeSubFolders;
                    watcher.Filter                = this.watcherInfo.FileFilter;
                    watcher.InternalBufferSize    = bufferSize;
                }

                if (HandleWatchesFilter(WatcherChangeTypes.Created)) 
                {
                    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_CreatedDeleted);
                }
                if (HandleWatchesFilter(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted))
                {
                    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_CreatedDeleted);
                }
                if (HandleWatchesFilter(WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed))
                {
                    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_Renamed);
                }
                if (watcherInfo.MonitorPathInterval > 0)
                {
                    watcher.EventPathAvailability += new PathAvailabilityHandler(watcher_EventPathAvailability);
                }
            }
            if (watcher != null)
            {
                if (this.watcherInfo.WatchForError)
                {
                    watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(watcher_Error);
                }
                if (this.watcherInfo.WatchForDisposed)
                {
                    watcher.Disposed += new EventHandler(watcher_Disposed);
                }
                this.watchers.Add(watcher);
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Starts all of the internal FileSystemWatcher objects by setting their 
        /// EnableRaisingEvents property to true.
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WatcherEx.Start()");
            this.watchers[0].StartFolderMonitor();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.watchers.Count; i++)
            {
                this.watchers[i].EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Stops all of the internal FileSystemWatcher objects by setting their 
        /// EnableRaisingEvents property to true.
        /// </summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WatcherEx.Stop()");
            this.watchers[0].StopFolderMonitor();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.watchers.Count; i++)
            {
                this.watchers[i].EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            }
        }
        #endregion Helper Methods

        #region Native Watcher Events
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring attribute changes is 
        /// triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedAttribute(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed Attribute");
            EventChangedAttribute(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.Attributes));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring creation time changes is 
        /// triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedCreationTime(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed CreationTime");
            EventChangedCreationTime(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.CreationTime));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring directory name changes is 
        /// triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedDirectoryName(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed DirectoryName");
            EventChangedDirectoryName(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.DirectoryName));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring file name changes is 
        /// triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedFileName(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed FileName");
            EventChangedFileName(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.FileName));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring last access date/time 
        /// changes is triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedLastAccess(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed LastAccess");
            EventChangedLastAccess(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.LastAccess));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring last write date/time 
        /// changes is triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedLastWrite(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed LastWrite");
            EventChangedLastWrite(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.LastWrite));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring security changes is 
        /// triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedSecurity(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed Security");
            EventChangedSecurity(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.Security));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the watcher responsible for monitoring size changes is 
        /// triggered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_ChangedSize(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed Size");
            EventChangedSize(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem, NotifyFilters.Size));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when an internal watcher is disposed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Disposed");
            EventDisposed(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.StandardEvent));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the main watcher detects an error (the watcher that detected the 
        /// error is part of the event's arguments object)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Error");
            EventError(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.Error));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the main watcher detects a file rename.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Renamed");
            EventRenamed(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.Renamed));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void watcher_CreatedDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.ChangeType)   
            {
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Created :
                    Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Created");
                    EventCreated(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem));
                    break;
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted :
                    Debug.WriteLine("EVENT - Changed Deleted");
                    EventDeleted(this, new WatcherExEventArgs(sender as FileSystemWatcherEx, e, ArgumentType.FileSystem));
                    break;
            }
        }

......
```

In another file B.cs, the main UI, I am trying to invoke these event response functions defined in A.cs, using something like this:

```
void fileWatcher_EventCreated(object sender, WatcherExEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, _fileWatcher.EventCreated());
    }
```

But I kep getting error that says `_fileWatcher.EventCreated()` can only be on the left side of += or -=...

I was trying to do the whole thing in B.cs (CS file of UI), as something like this:

```
void fileWatcher_EventDeleted(object sender, WatcherExEventArgs e)
        {
            Action EventDeleted = delegate()
            {
                _lvie.fileName = ((FileSystemEventArgs)(e.Arguments)).FullPath;
                _lvie.fileEvent = "Deleted";
                _lvie.timeOfOccurance = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
                listView1.Items.Add(_lvie);
            };

            listView1.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, EventDeleted);            
        }
```

but it did not responding file change events well. It seemed it did not pick some events.

I am just wondering how should I do this: In the main UI (A.cs) invoking the response event functions in background thread (B.cs)? Or should I do it in any other ways? Any suggestions is very appreciated. Thanks. I am very new to CS, so please bear with my ignority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) can only be raised from inside the class in which they exist.

Class B cannot raise an Event which exists in class A.

The closest workaround you could achieve is to create a new API function from within class A, called - for example - "RaiseMyEvent," which manually raises the event from inside class A; call that function from class B.

```
public class A
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent = null;

    public void RaiseMyEvent(EventArgs args)
    {
        var handler = MyEvent;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }
}

//Then, from inside class B:
myInstanceOfA.RaiseMyEvent();  //This will cause A to raise its own event
```

Comment: OK, so that means I need to create a series of delegate functions in A, which calls function in B? Is there an example of implementation? A very simple one will help. Thanks.

Comment: I am using something like: listView1.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, EventDeleted);  to invoke an event which is defined by 2nd parameter "EventDeleted"; I think this event has to be a delegate? So how do I define this delegate in B?

Comment: It sounds like in this instance, your delegate would be the "RaiseMyEvent" function; "blahblah.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, RaiseMyEvent)"